# About Soundcloud scraping for uploading music to telegram group

Tags: python, web-scraping, ffmpeg, soundcloud

I am trying to automatically download the new uploaded file from the below soundcloud link and upload it to a telegram group :

https://soundcloud.com/radio-hamrah-1

so I have googled the:

> [python script to download from soundcloud and import to telegram
> group](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03Wm5YYRqs8n9-GDaMFeBEKLxwvoQ:1623837078576&q=python%20script%20to%20download%20from%20soundcloud%20and%20import%20to%20telegram%20group&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3-_bB8JvxAhVW_J4KHZdRDawQBSgAegQIARAz)

and tried the [scdl](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/flyingrub-scdl-python-third-party-apis-wrappers) python module by [its instruction](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/flyingrub-scdl-python-third-party-apis-wrappers), but when I have tried its on [this colab page](https://colab.research.google.com/github/elasa-Sites/scdl/blob/master/Souncloud_scraper.ipynb#scrollTo=3GmqPCJxZIKs) I get this error:

```
!pip3 install git+https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl
!scdl -l https://soundcloud.com/pandadub/sets/the-lost-ship --download-archive archive.txt -c

Collecting git+https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl
  Cloning https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl to /tmp/pip-req-build-0g64ql2f
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl /tmp/pip-req-build-0g64ql2f
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scdl==1.6.12 from git+https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: docopt in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scdl==1.6.12) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mutagen in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scdl==1.6.12) (1.45.1)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scdl==1.6.12) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scdl==1.6.12) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: clint in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scdl==1.6.12) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests->scdl==1.6.12) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests->scdl==1.6.12) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests->scdl==1.6.12) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests->scdl==1.6.12) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: args in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from clint->scdl==1.6.12) (0.1.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: scdl
  Building wheel for scdl (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for scdl: filename=scdl-1.6.12-cp37-none-any.whl size=19143 sha256=27ca560a7f3947830289d0df167db84137d1554fe1ab740c2afab3db0abedd74
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-agspvyq5/wheels/49/44/6e/a5f6f709e7b231f3639ea9f9fc48a4699b958850715556e7f6
Successfully built scdl
Soundcloud Downloader
Failed to get item...
```

[image]

and when I try by [the Docker VPS](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/) by this commands:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl
pip3 install ffmpeg
scdl -l https://soundcloud.com/pandadub/sets/the-lost-ship --download-archive archive.txt -c
```

pip3 install git+https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl
pip3 install ffmpeg
scdl -l https://soundcloud.com/pandadub/sets/the-lost-ship --download-archive archive.txt -c

I get this error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg'
```

[image]

So I asked abut how could i do it by **[scdl](https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl)** and **[soundcloude](https://github.com/yackx/SoundCloud)** python module.

**Update:**

Based of my two comment on this question I get different result by using the [**scdl**](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/flyingrub-scdl-python-third-party-apis-wrappers) python module via [the above colab page](https://colab.research.google.com/github/elasa-Sites/scdl/blob/master/Souncloud_scraper.ipynb#scrollTo=3GmqPCJxZIKs), sometimes it is working and sometimes not, which i guess it is because of **soudncloud server setting** for preventing huge scraping and needs some delay during the music scraping form the **soundcloud**.

Thanks.

Comment: it is working on [colab page](https://colab.research.google.com/github/elasa-Sites/scdl/blob/master/Souncloud_scraper.ipynb) now and i guess the reason for problem with the `scdl python module` was using the `pip` command instead of using`pip3` for installing it, but the problem with `soundcloude python module` still remind.

Comment: Also i added the telegram uploading codes at [the above colab page](https://colab.research.google.com/github/elasa-Sites/scdl/blob/master/Souncloud_scraper.ipynb#scrollTo=XH3lVg7BYKRM)which are not completed!